# Scraping multiple pages of Zillow

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am attempting to scrape about 54 "Agent listings" and 11 "Other listings" between two pages on Zillow using the website included below, but my code is only yielding the first 20 results of the "Agent listings" on the first page of search results. How can I modify my code to get all results on all pages for both "Agent listings" and "Other listings"?

```
res_all <-NULL

for (page_result in 1:40) {
  zillow_url = paste0("https://www.zillow.com/providence-ri/duplex/?searchQueryState=%7B%22pagination%22%3A%7B%7D%2C%22usersSearchTerm%22%3A%22Providence%2C%20RI%22%2C%22mapBounds%22%3A%7B%22west%22%3A-71.48892251635742%2C%22east%22%3A-71.36017648364258%2C%22south%22%3A41.77131876826507%2C%22north%22%3A41.862664689400106%7D%2C%22regionSelection%22%3A%5B%7B%22regionId%22%3A26637%2C%22regionType%22%3A6%7D%5D%2C%22isMapVisible%22%3Atrue%2C%22filterState%22%3A%7B%22sort%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3A%22globalrelevanceex%22%7D%2C%22ah%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22sf%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22tow%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22con%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22apco%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22land%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22apa%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22manu%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%7D%2C%22isListVisible%22%3Atrue%2C%22mapZoom%22%3A13%7D")

zpg = read_html(zillow_url)

zillow_pg <-tibble(
  addr = zpg %>% html_nodes(".list-card-addr") %>% html_text(),
  price = zpg %>% html_nodes(".list-card-price") %>% html_text(),
  details = zpg %>% html_nodes(".list-card-details") %>% html_text() ,
  heading= zpg %>% html_nodes(".list-card-info a") %>% html_text() ,
  type = zpg %>% html_nodes(".list-card-statusText") %>% html_text())


res_all <- distinct(bind_rows(res_all, zillow_pg))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `RSelenium` as the page is dynamically loaded.

Here is a partial answer to extract prices.

**Launch browser**

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(RSelenium)
driver = rsDriver(browser = c("firefox"))
remDr <- driver[["client"]]
remDr$navigate(url)
```

**Now load all the listings**

```
remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', value = '//*[@id="grid-search-results"]/div[1]/h1')$clickElement()
webElem <- remDr$findElement("css", "body")
#scrolling to the end of webpage. 
webElem$sendKeysToElement(list(key = "end"))
webElem$sendKeysToElement(list(key = "home"))
```

**Repeat the last two steps if you can't get prices of all the listings.**

```
remDr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% 
  read_html()   %>% 
  html_nodes(".list-card-price") %>% html_text()
 [1] "$399,999"   "$449,900"   "$399,000"   "$469,900"   "$310,000"   "$319,900"   "$404,900"   "$320,000"   "$529,000"   "$750,000"   "$335,000"   "$299,000"  
[13] "$349,900"   "$314,900"   "$369,999"   "$359,000"   "$149,900"   "$309,900"   "$377,000"   "$360,000"   "$699,900"   "$410,000"   "$634,900"   "$310,000"  
[25] "$695,000"   "$395,000"   "$339,900"   "$399,900"   "$350,000"   "$369,900"   "$639,000"   "$3,995,000" "$799,000"   "$699,000"   "$349,000"   "$448,000"
```

**Now going to page 2, to get remaining listings**

```
remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', value = '//*[@id="grid-search-results"]/div[3]/nav/ul/li[5]/a')$clickElement()
remDr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% 
  read_html()   %>% 
  html_nodes(".list-card-price") %>% html_text()
 [1] "$575,000"   "$299,000"   "$369,900"   "$345,500"   "$799,000"   "$380,000"   "$300,000"   "$1,295,000" "$575,000"   "$575,000"   "$599,900"   "$799,000"  
[13] "$474,900"   "$399,900"
```

**Now get prices from other listing section.**

```
remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', value = '//*[@id="grid-search-results"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/button[2]')$clickElement()
remDr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% 
  read_html()   %>% 
  html_nodes(".list-card-price") %>% html_text()
 [1] "$315,000"      "$350,000"      "$439,000"      "$350,000"      "$395,000"      "$315,000"      "Est. $396,600" "Est. $681,300" "$234,000"     
[10] "$449,900"      "$249,900"      "Est. $310,300"
```